# How to inject runtime data to object created when parsing XML using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have to parse a complex XML document. Some of classes in my model implement interface `HasDate`:

```
interface HasDate {
    public void setDate(Date date);
}
```

The date is known when unmarshaller is created:

```
// here I know the date.
JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.mycompany.mymodel");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = ctx.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.unmarshal(input);
```

I would like to call `setDate()` for each instance of class that implements `HasDate` while JAXB is parsing the document.

Here are 2 solution I know myself:
I can annotation each relevant class as following:

```
@XmlType(factoryClass = ObjectFactory.class, factoryMethod = "createMyObject")
```

The method `createMyObject()` will call `setDate()`. The problem with this solution is that `createMyObject()` must be static. Setting information as static member makes solution not thread safe.

As a variant of this solution I can put the date to `ThreadLocal` just before parsing. `createMyObject()` will read date from  `ThreadLocal` and call `setDate()`. This solution is thread safe but looks like a patch.

Other solution is to discover the object graph created by JAXB using reflection, traverse it recursively and call `setDate()` when needed. This solution is thread safe but requires some implementation efforts and needs maintenance in future.

I wonder whether JAXB has other, built-in solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement an `Unmarshaller.Listener` and set it on the `Unmarshaller`.  Then on the `afterUnmarshal` method if the target class is an instance of `HasDate` then you could call the `setDate` method on it.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.Listener.html

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `@XmlAdapter` for all those classes that implement `HasDate` interface. This makes your use-case explicit and type-safe. You can have a base adapter that understands to lookup the date from ThreadLocal.

[XmlAdapter: JAXB's secret weapon](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html)

If this option is not going to work then I like the reflection approach being invoked in the [afterUnmarshall](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.Listener.html#afterUnmarshal%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) life-cycle method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read articles you sent me and prefer to use `listener.afterUnmarshal()`